# Why resnet model size is 3 times bigger than VGG in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

I applied transfer learning for image analysis and used two pre-trained models on Keras: ResNeXt50 and VGG16. (https://keras.io/applications/#resnet)

I use the convolution layers of both models and add 1 FC layers (1024 neurons) on top of them. After training, I saved them as .h5 files and find something weird.

The size of saved VGG16 model is about 300MB, while the size of saved ResNeXt50 model is over 900MB, which is more than 3 times of VGG16! But based on the document (https://keras.io/applications/#resnet) as well as the paper, ResNeXt50 should have much fewer weights than VGG16 and much smaller size.

Does anyone know why my save ResNeXt50 model has such big size?

Thanks!

Comment: This is only answerable if you include actual code that trains these models, it could just be that you are using Adam with ResNeXt50.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thank you for the answer. I tried both Adam and SGD and the save models are all very big. Could you talk about how to estimate the size of the saved model? Or is there anything I can read to learn how to estimate?

Comment: That was not an answer, it was a comment telling you to provide additional information.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, thank you for the comments and here are the details. For VGG16, I tried both SGD (optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, decay=5e-5, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=1.0)) and Adam (optimizer = optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0, amsgrad=True)). And the saved model size are quite silimilar.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Here is the the training code for VGG16 (applications.VGG16) is model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                        epochs=epochs,
                        steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator) / batch_size,
                        validation_data=val_generator,
                        validation_steps=len(val_generator) / batch_size,
                        callbacks=[csv_logger_finetune, checkpoint])

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro For Resnext50(model = applications.resnet50.ResNet50), I used the exactly data and SGD optimizer as below, which is the same as VGG16, optimizer = optimizers.SGD(lr=lr, decay=5e-5, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=1.0). Model training code is the same, too. The saved model size of VGG16 is 308MB, while resnext50 is 964MB.